# Subspaces Question

Tags: vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND6ft.png)

The following happen to all be true. But why is this closed under scalar multiplication?
α[[a],[3a+b],[4a+4b],[4a+3b]] =[[aα],[3aα+bα],[4aα+4bα],[4aα+3bα]] and sure, this is in ***R*** but this is NOT in the subset so is it not closed?

Please comment if you can not see picture :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem, clearly
$$\alpha
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ 3a+b \\ 4a+4b \\ 4a+3b
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{\alpha a} \\ 3(\color{red}{\alpha a})+(\color{blue}{\alpha b}) \\ 4(\color{red}{\alpha a})+4(\color{blue}{\alpha b}) \\ 4(\color{red}{\alpha a})+3(\color{blue}{\alpha b})
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is in the form of $$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{u} \\ 3\color{red}{u}+\color{blue}{v} \\ 4\color{red}{u}+4\color{blue}{v} \\ 4\color{red}{u}+3\color{blue}{v}
\end{bmatrix}.$$